# Trying to sort the details by Sequence_ID . but when it comes to Extract the file and send using Automation.it is not in correct format

Tags: marketing-cloud

Trying to sort the details by Sequence_ID . but when it comes to Extract the file and send using Automation. it is not in correct format how i can see in the Data extension.

```sql
Select
Sequence_ID,
Channel,
Customer_ID,
[Form ID],
Questionnaire_1_Answer,
Questionnaire_2_A_Answer,
Age,
Created_Date,
FROM PROD_DrCiLabo_JP_Genomer_CampaignDE_ENH_62264
ORDER BY  Created_Date ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS
```

in the email attachment it in reverse format

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! I don't know anything about SFMC, and outside of that I am honestly not fully understanding your question. But in case this helps I'll point out that your SQL statement there is being sorted (`ORDER BY`) Created Date. If you want this sorted by Sequence ID, you should `ORDER BY Sequence_ID`.

Comment: there is no guarantee that an extract will mimic the order you see in the UI